# PHP write a conditional statement based on whether an argument is in a database or not

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am developing a wordpress plugin. There is a variable that I send to the database once a payment has been made, that is `ispayment` and it is set to 1. If the payment has not been made, then the variable is not sent to the database...so there is an instance where, for a particular post ID, the variable "ispayment" does not exist.

I'm now trying to write a conditional statement based on whether this variable is present or not.

What I'm trying to say is, if wedding_form_final_submit = 1 AND there is no ispayment variable - $status = foo. Else, if wedding_form_final_submit = 1 AND ispayment = 1, $status = bar.

Here is what I have so far:

```
if(get_post_meta($post_id,'wedding_form_final_submit', 1) && get_post_meta($post_id, 'ispayment',false)) {
            $status = 'Form Complete';
        } elseif(get_post_meta($post_id,'wedding_form_final_submit', 1) && get_post_meta($post_id, 'ispayment',true)) {
            $status = 'Deposit Paid';
        } else {
            $status = '';
        }
```

Currently, this just returns "Form Complete" but it's for an entry that should return Deposit Paid, the entry that should say Form Complete is just blank.

I believe my issue is that for my first statement, the variable ispayment doesn't exist. How do I ammend this though?

Comment: You need to check the return value of `get_post_meta`. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

Comment: Thanks @CharlotteDunois - how do I do this though if the variable doesn't even exist yet in the DB - that is what I'm trying to test. essentially, does the entry "ispayment" exist

Comment: The function reference states that if the argument `single` is set to true the function will return an empty string. If the argument is set to false, an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code below will probably do, if the post meta you're retrieving doesn't exist, your variable just return empty

```
// get post meta value 'ispayment'
$paid = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'ispayment', true );

//Check where post meta exists and value is 1
if ( isset($paid) && $paid === '1' ) {
     $status = 'Form Complete';
//If post meta doesn't exist or value is not 1.
} else {
    $status = 'Deposit Paid';
}

//or shorter

$paid = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'ispayment', true );

$status = ( isset($paid) && $paid === '1' ) ? 'Form Complete' : 'Deposit Paid';
```

just add your other code in there